# Why is this making my program to print twice?

Tags: python

A function for writing in text file makes my code to be printed twice. What to do?

```
def votes():
    print("voter id")
    return ("voter id")

def v():
    print("please vote")
    return ("please vote")

def f():
    file =open("elections.txt","w")
    file.write(str(votes()))
    file.write(str(v()))
    file.close()

votes()
v()
f()
```

Comment: Should I delete return?

Comment: Or any other Way is there?

Comment: Yes...I want it to get printed in both file and terminal

Comment: Remove the `votes()` and `v()` before the last line

Comment: It's printing twice in the terminal

Comment: It's working...

Comment: Another problem is coming

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls the `votes` function two times.  Each time it is called, it prints `voter id` to STDOUT.  The same goes for the `v` function.  That is why you get duplicated messages on STDOUT.

Here is one way to get it to print once to STDOUT and once to the file:

```
def votes():
    return ("voter id")

def v():
    return ("please vote")

def f():
    file =open("elections.txt","w")
    file.write(str(votes()))
    file.write(str(v()))
    file.close()

print(votes())
print(v())
f()
```

Answer (score 0):

It display twice because of the calling order

`votes()` will print `voter id`
`v()` will print `please vote`
`f()` call `votes()` so print `voter id` take the return of the function and write it to the file. but also call `v()` that will diplsay `please vote`

so if you only call `f()`
You will write in the file and have no duplicate output on terminal

best regards